# How to restrict users from reading data from Firestore documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- UidOne (document)
   |          |
   |          --- userName: "UserOne"
   |
   --- items (collection)
         |
         --- ItemIdOne (document)
         |     |
         |     --- itemName: "ItemOne"
         |
         --- ItemIdTwo
               |
               --- itemName: "ItemTwo"
```

What I want to achieve is to restrict every user from reading item names from each document within `items` collection using security rules. This is how I do it:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /items/{item} {
            allow read, write: if false;
        }
    }
}
```

To display the item names I use the following query:

```
Query query = itemsRef.orderBy("itemName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
```

When I try to compile my app I get the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

But the item names are still displayed in my `RecyclerView`. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check to see if your items are still coming from the local cache.

From [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) page add this to your OnEvent

```
       String source = querySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache() ?
                    "local cache" : "server";
            Log.d(TAG, "Data fetched from " + source);
```

If it is reading from the local cache you can set PersistenceEnabled(false) like this (also mentioned on that page):

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Even if you are online it will read from the local snapshot, and only updates the snapshot if the data changes.  It's your rules that changed not your data. I found when testing with it set to true I got some unexpected results.  I find I prefer it to be false when testing and changing code/rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm always online.

Comment: It will still read from the local snapshot even when online.  Sorry I was on the train when I wrote this answer I have added the code and the link to the Firestore page.  I hope this helps, your rules look fine to me and you are getting the expected permission denied.